# SQL Query: Game server. If I break the query down, it works. If I put it all together, it fails

Tags: sql, sql-insert

The query is:

insert into char_inventory (charid,location,slot,itemid,quantity) values (select charid from chars where charid not in (select charid from char_inventory where itemid=65535),0,0,65535,10000);

Comment: i put () around the select charid from chars and i get " you can't specify targe table 'char_inventory' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
insert into char_inventory (charid,location,slot,itemid,quantity)
    select charid,0,0,65535,10000
    from chars
    where charid not in (select charid from char_inventory where itemid=65535)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement with `LEFT JOIN`

```
INSERT INTO char_inventory (charid, location, slot, itemid, quantity) 
SELECT  chars.charid, 0 , 0, 65535, 10000
FROM    chars
        LEFT JOIN char_inventory
            ON  chars.charid = char_inventory.charid AND
                char_inventory.itemid = 65535
WHERE   char_inventory.charid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
insert into char_inventory (charid,location,slot,itemid,quantity) 
select charid,0,0,65535,10000 from chars where charid not in (select charid from char_inventory where itemid=65535)
```